# Sum of 1/n^4 using a half period cosine series

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-series, parsevals-identity

I am aware that I can solve the $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^4},$$ using a a cosine series for $x^2$ on the half period $0<x<2$ however I am wondering if I can also solve this by using the cosine half series for x and applying parsavels identity.

The result gives a series of $$\ {\int_{0}^2x^2 dx}=   b+a\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(2n+1)^4},$$ where b and a are real numbers, thus giving me a sum for the odd terms.
I am unsure how to compute the even terms with this method any help would be appreciated

Comment: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^4}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(2n)^4}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(2n-1)^4}$$ hence $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(2n-1)^4}=\dfrac{15}{16}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^4}$$

Comment: ah beautiful, thankyou sir

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is worth noting that, generalization to any power (i.e., other than the given case 4!) is possible here.
The Riemann Zeta function $\zeta(s)$ and the complementary function Dirichlet alternating zeta function $\eta(s)$

\begin{eqnarray*}
\zeta(s) &=& \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n^{s}}} \\
\eta(s) &=& -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n^{s}}} 
\end{eqnarray*}

are related by
\begin{eqnarray}
\eta(s) &=& \left(1-2^{1-s}\right)\zeta(s)
\end{eqnarray},

Also,

\begin{eqnarray*}
2   \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{(2 m)^{s}}}  &=&  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n^{s}}}  + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n^{s}}} \\
&=&  2 \left(2^{-s}\right) \zeta(s) \\
2   \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{(2 m-1)^{s}}}  &=&   \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n^{s}}}  - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n^{s}}}  \\
&=& 2 \left(1-2^{-s}\right) \zeta(s)
\end{eqnarray*}

The odd and even sum respectively becomes,

\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{(2 m)^{s}}}  &=& 2^{-s}\zeta(s) \\
\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{(2 m-1)^{s}}}  &=&  \left(1-2^{-s}\right) \zeta(s)
\end{eqnarray*}

In the particular case $s=4$, it becomes $\frac{1}{16} \zeta(4)$ and $\frac{15}{16} \zeta(4)$ as Jean-Claude Arbaut  arrived at.

Comment: +1 for the nice answer